# Distribute automatically and equitly on EXCEL, in a certain number of cells, the result of the division of two numbers

Tags: excel, decimal, formula, equality

Ok this is my problem.

I have the an total shipping cost( in this example 14.6) that normallys is a decimal number. This number have to be divide by the quantity of products that cames in a box( in this example 6). Giving a result of 2.433333

I have to complete the Shipping cost column equally with the result already mentioned. But by only taking into account the rounded number 2.43 (because we are talking about money) it leaves me out the decimal number 0.02, which in this case could not leave out since we are talking about money.

Therefore the sum of the shipping cost gives me 14.58 and not 14.60

What would be the formula that I should implement to solve this problem?

Distribute automatically  and equitly on EXCEL, in a certain number of cells, the result of the division of two numbers

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want the output to look? Eg in your example, you could have the first 2 items out of the box costing 2.44 to ship, and the remainder 2.43.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a `=Round()` function, which makes it possible to round up to a number of decimals:

```
=Round(1.234,2) => 1.23
=Round(1.345,2) => 1.35
```

There are also the functions `=RoundDown()` or `=RoundUp()` in case you always want to round down to zero or up to the skies :-) (`RoundDown(1.99,0)` gives 1 and `RoundUp(1.01,0)` returns 2).

Earlier there were the functions `=Floor()` and `=Ceiling()` but those don't work (well) when rounding up to integer values (`=Floor(x,0)` gives a division by zero exception and `Ceiling(x,0)` always returns zero).

Comment: That is not the OP's issue.